# TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool

Tags: solidity

```
 function allowance (address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining )
      if **(__allowances[_owner][msg.sender])**{
          **^-------------------------------^**
            return __allowances[_owner][msg.sender];
      }
            return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Well if it's not implicitly convertible, then convert it explicitly! And BTW, your "question" is very badly phrased.

Comment: To avoid some type of errors that are hard to debug Solidity forbid implicit conversion. And some like bool <-> uint256 are not possible at all. It is better if you explictely check for `__allowances[_owner][msg.sender] > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The "if statement" returns a bool condition,(being true or false), and likely should have a comparison going on..

In your case there is no comparison (> == etc) going on, and just returning a number.